# Searching in collection with self referencing objects

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection:

```
{
_id - ObjectId
name - string
location - string
..
parentId - ObjectId //link to parent object
}
```

I have a filter query and it works nice even with int values (in C#):

```
var q = Query.Matches(column, new BsonRegularExpression(string.Format("/^{0}/i", name)));
```

What should I do in order to search by the name of parent object? Of cause, using LINQ, there is no problem, but is it possible to conduct searching on the server side?

Comment: For that you'd need a (self-)join, and you cannot do that in MongoDB. Split it into two queries, first find the documents that match the name, and then get their children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not way to search by referenced object fields in mongodb. And in general monogdb is not relational database, so in my opinion it should not support any relations at all.

There is good known approach it is create additional field and store (denormalize) information on what you want search.

So, change your schema as follow to search on parent object name:

```
{
_id - ObjectId
name - string
location - string
..
parentId - ObjectId //link to parent object,
parentName
}
```

The main idea you should understand: mongodb is not realtional, no joins here, no relations.

Comment: I understand, just want to make it smaller. I have a unique index on Name + Location, so maybe I can make it an _id [name, location], and link parentId [name, location].

Comment: @1gn1ter: yea, it's also good solution in case if pair [name, location] unique. And it will give you ability easy search on parent name.

Answer (score 5):

There are no joins in MongoDB, but you basically have two options:

*Solution 1:*

1. Query by the name and fetch the result (the parents)
2. For every document fetched, query again and fetch all documents where the `_id` and the `parentId` match (the children)

*Solution 2:*

Additionally to the `parentId`, also save the name of the parent's `name` with each document and query directly for `parentName`