# how to access from grandfather to grandson documents with mongoid + rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

```
class User
 include Mongoid::Document
 has_many :orders
 has_one :payments
end

class Order
 include Mongoid::Document
 belongs_to :user
 has_one :payment, dependent: :destroy, :autosave => true
end

class Payment
 include Mongoid::Document
 belongs_to :order
 belongs_to :user
ebd
```

`user_controller.rb` on `jobs` action:

```
def jobs
 #
 #
 jobs = Order.where(:seller_id => current_user.id).order_by :created_at, :desc
 @jobs = []
 for j in jobs
  if j.payment.preapproval_key != nil && j.payment.correlation_id != nil && j.payment.approved == true
   @jobs << j
  end
 end
 #
 #
end
```

Is possible filter all jobs with `payment.preapproval_key != nil && payment.correlation_id != nil && payment.approved == true` without using this loop?

**There is a better way to do this?**

Comment: So you want to do a self-join in MongoDB?

Comment: Thank you! I need get all jobs with these conditions. I don't know if exist a best way do it!

Comment: The problem is that MongoDB doesn't support joins at all so self-joins are out of the question. I think you're left with your current approach (which might be expensive) or denormalizing and maintaining duplicated data. You might just have a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8269162/479863

Comment: I know that mongod doesn't support joins. But I thought there was a better way to do this without using an array. I do not want to duplicate data in the database so stay the approach to this issue as it is. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something on following lines, still few db requests, but that is to be expected due to unavailability of joins. But it would be lesser than db requests you are doing now:

```
all_order_ids = Order.where(:seller_id => current_user.id).only(:_id).map(&:id)
payments = Payment.where(:order_id.in => all_order_ids, 
                         :preapproval_key.ne => nil,
                         :correlation_id.ne => nil,
                         :approved => true)
jobs = Order.where(:_id.in => payments.only(:order_id).map(&:order_id))
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for delay. This code is working fine :D. This code is better in performance than using an array? Thank you very much!